# 2d grid - Sum of reachable destinations

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, grid, path-finding

Let's say I have a 2d grid, a starting point S and a maximum walking distance W.
I want to sum all the reachable distances, excluding the overlapping ones begining from S and walking W. I.e., imagining the grid bellow

> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_* 
>   |X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
>   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
>   |X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
>   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** 
>   |X|X|X|X|X|**S**|X|X|X|X|X|
>   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** 
>   |X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
>   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

where I can only use the lines to walk. There're two additional details.
One, the fact that when you start in the road above S you can start in the middle of this block (and not necessarily in both ends). The second is that crossing streets also have a cost in terms of maximum distance. Ideas or suggestions are welcome.

I was unsuccessfully trying to do it in Vba and R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So to clarify, S can only move up/down, or left/right?

Comment: Can move through the lines (up/down, left/right). The example may be misrepresenting the idea...

"S"should be over the the line above it. Imagine this a residential neighborhood (the X would represent the blocks) and I want to sum the size of all paths reachable from S, but I don't to double count paths.

Comment: Do you count a destination multiple times if it can be reached by multiple paths? Do you allow paths that retrace steps such as {up,down,up,down,up,down,right}?

Comment: The best way I can explain this is: imagine a grid representing a set of blocks and streets and that i have to put a garage parking in a block of this area. Then how could i measure the distance that everyone would be able to walk, starting from this point, considering a specific maximum walking distance?

Comment: I'm still not certain why (or how) you're summing the destinations, but it sounds like you just want a breadth-first search from the starting point with the distances as edge weights.